# Probability That One Player Gets All 13 Cards Of The Same Kind

Tags: probability

lets there be 4 players.

What is the possibility that one player will 13 cards from the same kind?

there are $52\choose13,13,13,13$ ways to deal 4 players 13 cards.

If one get all 13 from one kind there are $4*{39\choose13,13,13}$.

Where did this 4 came from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4: does the player get all hearts, or all diamonds, or all clubs or all spades?  (4 choices)

Comment: just thought about it, thanks a lot!

Comment: It gets more complicated if you want the probably that any one of the four players gets a full suit.